# When using chrome/chromium, brackets in url's hash is shown as %5Bwhatever%5D. Using firefox [whatever]. There is any way to fix it?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, hash

I's using jQuery 1.4.3 and the BBQ plugin to handle history and hash.

When I update the hash with that string 
"listing=restaurants&search[province]=1&search[main_food]=2"
the url bar shows
"listing=restaurants&search%5Bprovince%5D=1&search%5Bmain_food%5D=2"

Ugly.

There is any way to show it nice, like firefox does?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The characters `[` and `]` must not appear literally in the [fragment of a URI](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.5). Here’s the corresponding [ABNF for URI (RFC 3986)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#appendix-A):

> ```
> fragment      = *( pchar / "/" / "?" )
> pchar         = unreserved / pct-encoded / sub-delims / ":" / "@"
> unreserved    = ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" / "~"
> pct-encoded   = "%" HEXDIG HEXDIG
> sub-delims    = "!" / "$" / "&" / "'" / "(" / ")"
>               / "*" / "+" / "," / ";" / "="
> ```

Any character that is not listed her must be encoded using the percent-encoding. So Chrome’s behavior is correct. But I guess Firefox is just displaying the characters that are represented by `%5B` and `%5D`. And that’s up to the browser.